# Cannot display toast in handler (sending message to a Handler on a dead thread)

Tags: android, handler, background-service

I am trying to run the background service periodically. I am using IntentService for background service along with the handler. But when I try to use Toast to confirm that service is running periodically logcat throws sending message to a Handler on a dead thread. Also when I try to use getMainLooper in handler the application doesnot run. Logcat gives "NetworkOnMainThreadException" What should I do?

```
package com.example.income;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.*;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Background extends IntentService
{   
    public Background()
    {
        super("This is the simple background classes");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finally can I do it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("message","This is simple background services");
                Db db =new Db(Background.this,"simple",null,4);
                Cursor c= db.getData();
                if( c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    List<Map<String, String>> contacts = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                    do
                    {
                        String num,dater;
                        int integer;
                        integer=c.getInt (c.getColumnIndex(Base.Identifier));
                        num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Base.CONTACTS));
                        dater =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Base.DATE));

                        Map<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        contact.put("date", dater);
                        contact.put("contact", num);
                        contact.put("id",String.valueOf(integer));
                        contacts.add(contact);
                  }
                    while (c.moveToNext());

                    try
                    {
                        sendData(contacts);             

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        });

}

    public void sendData(List<Map<String, String>> contacts) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException 
    {
        Log.v("Let's C","Will it go here?");

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.116/android1.php");

            Log.v("p","this");
            Log.d("Contacts", Integer.toString(contacts.size()));

            JSONArray array= new JSONArray(contacts);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forward",array.toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response=  httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String idstring=myJsonObject.optString("id").toString();
            JSONArray idarray = new JSONArray(idstring);

            int[] intArray = new int[idarray.length()];

            Db db =new Db(Background.this,"simple",null,4); 
            for(int i=0;i<idarray.length();i++)
            {
                Log.i("successfully deleting]","deleted");
                intArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(idarray.getString(i));
                db.deletedata(intArray[i]);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in `AsyncTask` in the Android framework.

It expects this to be initialized on the main thread, but that is not guaranteed since it will be initialized on whichever thread happens to cause the class to run its static initializers. I reproduced this issue where the Handler references a worker thread.

Try this code:

```
public class Background extends IntentService
{   
    Handler mMainThreadHandler = null;

    public Background() {
        super("This is the simple background classes");
        mMainThreadHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {

        mMainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finally can I do it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("message","This is simple background services");
                Db db =new Db(Background.this,"simple",null,4);
                Cursor c= db.getData();
                if( c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    List<Map<String, String>> contacts = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                    do
                    {
                        String num,dater;
                        int integer;
                        integer=c.getInt (c.getColumnIndex(Base.Identifier));
                        num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Base.CONTACTS));
                        dater =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Base.DATE));

                        Map<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        contact.put("date", dater);
                        contact.put("contact", num);
                        contact.put("id",String.valueOf(integer));
                        contacts.add(contact);
                  }
                    while (c.moveToNext());

                    try
                    {
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {

                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        try {
                            sendData(contacts);   
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }
                   }).start();


                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        });

}
```

**EDIT:**

Your `sendData()` is performing network calls. This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. you need to call `sendData()` method in another thread.

Comment: I am sorry but the same problem. Log cat says NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: please then provide me the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is due to  Net-work-operation your are trying to perform on main thread

Just do one thing

```
public class SendContacts extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    List<Map<String, String>> contacts;


    public SendContacts(List<Map<String, String>> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public SendContacts() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        sendData(contacts);

        return null;
    }
}
```

where you are calling `sendData(contacts);`

replace with this

```
new SendContacts(contacts).execute();
```